# static behaviour->objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have this `static` declaration of `m_pData=1099656` in a `class`.

In `main` `NSLog(@"Testing:%d",m_pData);`

Its printing me `0`.

How to get the same value of `m_pData` in the class in the main function too.

I cant use `obj.m_pData` or `obj->m_pData` to acces the variable.

EDITED:

```
test2.m
----------


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "data_derived.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    data* dat = [data alloc];
    requestSession* session = [requestSession alloc];
    [session init];

    [dat TxCreateImage:RM_REQUEST_SESSION];
    NSLog(@"Testing:%d",m_pData); //the static variable is not printing the value its holding.Its printing Zero.If printed the same variable inside the class it gives some numbers.
    [dat dataBuffer:&m_pData withLen:&m_uDataSize]; //here the actual values of static values are not passed.when printed both of them contains zero values.

    [pool drain];
    return 0;

}

data.h
--------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "remote.h"

static int m_nMessageId;      //Message ID
static int m_uSessionId;      //Session ID
static int m_chSequenceChar;  //Sequence ID

static int* m_pData;          //Integer buffer to carry data
static int m_uDataSize;       //Datasize

@interface data : NSObject {

    @public


}

- (id)initWithID:(int) uMessageId withData:(id)pData withSize:(size_t) uDataSize;
+ (void)initialize;
- (void)dealloc;
- (id) dataBuffer:(int**)m_Data withLen:(int**)uLen;
- (BOOL) TxCreateImage:(int)messageId;

@end

data.m
---------

#import "data.h"

#define ENCODED_MSG_DATA_OFFSET 8

@implementation data

+ (void)initialize
{
    m_uSessionId    = 0;
    m_chSequenceChar= 0;

    // Initialize values from derived class
    m_nMessageId    = 0;
    m_pData         = 0;              
    m_uDataSize     = 0; 

}

- (id) initWithID:(int) uMessageId withData:(id)pData withSize:(size_t) uDataSize
{
        if(self=[super init])
        {
           // Initialize the member variables
            m_uSessionId    = 0xFF;
            m_chSequenceChar= 10;

           // Initialize values from derived class
            m_nMessageId    = uMessageId;
            m_pData         = (int*)pData;              
            m_uDataSize     = (int)uDataSize;            
        }
        NSLog(@"Data size:%d",uDataSize);
        NSLog(@"m_pData:%d",m_pData);
        NSLog(@"pData:%d",pData);

        return self;    
}

- (id) dataBuffer:(int**)m_Data withLen:(int**)uLen
{
       if ( m_uDataSize <= RMH_MAX_ENCODED_LENGTH )
       {
        int abBigEndian[RMH_MESSAGE_MAX_SIZE];
        memcpy(abBigEndian,m_Data,m_uDataSize);
        NSLog(@"m_Data:%d",*m_Data);
        NSLog(@"abBigEndian:%d",abBigEndian);
        uLen += ENCODED_CRC_BYTE_LEN + 1;
        NSLog(@"%d",*uLen);
        }

        NSLog(@"END!");
        return self;    
}

- (BOOL) TxCreateImage:(int)messageId
{
    char pData[4096];
    sprintf(pData,"%x  %d  %d  %d  %x",ASCII_STX,m_uSessionId,m_chSequenceChar,m_nMessageId,ASCII_ETX); //uLen = ENCODED_MSG_DATA_OFFSET;
    NSLog(@"%s",pData);
    return YES;
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

data_derived.h
---------------------


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "data.h"

#define DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(ClassID)\
enum                                 \
{                                    \
    ID = ClassID                     \
};                                   \

@interface requestSession : data {

@public
    DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(RM_REQUEST_SESSION);
    struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;
}

-(id)init;
-(void)dealloc;

@end

data_derived.m
---------------------


#import "data_derived.h"

@implementation requestSession

- (id)init
{
    size_t asize = sizeof(st);
    st.uDeviceID = RS232_PROTOCOL_DEVICE_ID;
    st.uProtocolVersion = RS232_VERSION;
    memset(st.uReserved,0x00,sizeof(st.uReserved));
    NSLog(@"Address of the structure:%d",&st);
    self=[super initWithID:ID withData:(id)&st withSize:asize];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: @Frank C:I have edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't place your static members in .h file. Move them to data.m.

Also about `static` keyword - in C (and Objective C, which is clear superset to C), when using `static` with global variables (like you do), it only indicates that this variables will be local to the file you declared these variable in. So global variables anyway have only one instance, with `static` modifier or without. If you don't use `static`, then you can access these variables from other files with `external` declaration, like:

```
// file1.m
int variable = 4;

// file2.m
external int variable; // variable == 4
```

That's why your code is printing you 0. `m_pData` in test2.m is not the same `m_pData` you have in data.m. Without `static` modifier you would get a linker error.

And you might want to write getters/setters for static members. Like:

```
+ (int *)pData {
    return m_pData; // or smth like memcpy
}
```